# Pythonのクラスから、スタティックフィールドの一覧を取得する方法

Tags: python, python3

Pythonのクラスに定義されている、スタティックフィールド（クラスの属性値、以下のvalue変数）を、一覧で取得したいのですが、
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？
以下のように、inspectパッケージのgetmembersメソッドを利用することで、
メソッドの一覧や、すべての属性の一覧は取得することができました。
スタティックフィールドのみの一覧を取得することは可能でしょうか。

以下のサイトにたどり着いたのですが、読み解けませんでした。。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/inspect.html

```
import inspect


class TestClass():
    value = '##'  # ←このフィールドと、その値をリフレクションで取得したい。

    def test_method(self, a: int = 1, b: str = '@@') -> str:
        print(a, b)
        return b


# functions = dict(inspect.getmembers(TestClass, inspect.isfunction))  # ←メソッドの一覧は取得できました。
functions = dict(inspect.getmembers(TestClass))
for key, func in functions.items():
    print(key, func)
```

以下は、実行結果です。
inspect.getmembers()メソッドで、value ##の行のみ抽出できないでしょうか？

```
__class__ <class 'type'>
__delattr__ <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>
__dict__ {'__module__': '__main__', 'value': '##', 'test_method': <function TestClass.test_method at 0x7f4a763bae50>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'TestClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'TestClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
__dir__ <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
__doc__ None
__eq__ <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
__format__ <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>
__ge__ <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>
__getattribute__ <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
__gt__ <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>
__hash__ <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>
__init__ <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
__init_subclass__ <built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x3bc3960>
__le__ <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>
__lt__ <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>
__module__ __main__
__ne__ <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>
__new__ <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x9085a0>
__reduce__ <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>
__reduce_ex__ <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>
__repr__ <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>
__setattr__ <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>
__sizeof__ <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>
__str__ <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
__subclasshook__ <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x3bc3960>
__weakref__ <attribute '__weakref__' of 'TestClass' objects>
test_method <function TestClass.test_method at 0x7f4a763bae50>
value ##
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[looping over all member variables of a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398022/9014308), [【Python】属性の一覧を取得する方法（２種類）](https://srbrnote.work/archives/4946)

Comment: ありがとうございます。全メンバ（メソッドや属性を含むすべて）を取得して、not callable(x)で除去する方法が記載されていますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import inspect

class TestClass():
    value = '##'

    def test_method(self, a: int = 1, b: str = '@@') -> str:
        print(a, b)
        return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class_variables = [i for i in inspect.getmembers(TestClass, predicate=lambda x: not callable(x))
                       if not i[0].startswith('_')]
    print(class_variables)

# [('value', '##')]
```

Comment: 期待通りの結果が得られました。ありがとうございます。メソッドかどうかラムダ式を指定して除去できること、'_'で始まるものも除去していること理解できました。